# Implementing Firebase Crashlytics in React native application - Android

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I want to add Firebase Crashlytics to my React native project. I had a look online and some of the links suggested using Crashlytics with Fabric,

When I looked at Fabric and at somepoint it was mentioned that it was only available till 2020 and recommended to use Firebase Crashlytics. I am a bit confused.

Can any one suggest any link/guide to implement Firebase Crashlytics in my React native project.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 5):

Its kind of simple.

First you need to add firebase to your project use the following link to link react-native-firebase .

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup

Then use there doc to add firebase crash analytics into your code

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/crashlytics/reference/crashlytics

for example:

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'

componentDidMount(){
  firebase.crashlytics().log('Test Message!');
  firebase.crashlytics().recordError(37,"Test Error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add firebase to your project followed by crashlytics sdk. You might need to put the keys in your android and ios projects. Thts it.

Also have a look at sentry- its more suitable for JS based apps as it shows the line nos and the code which caused the crash. Crashlytics on the other hand as i remember shows only native crashes.

Comment: Yes I do require JS based crash information. regarding Sentry are you referring to https://github.com/getsentry/react-native-sentry

Comment: Can we not get JS based crash information using Firebase Crashlytics

Comment: Yes - github.com/getsentry/react-native-sentry